# Sampling from a huge graph in networkx

Tags: python-2.7, graph, bigdata, networkx

I am going to sample from a huge Graph(about a 1.5M edges and 0.5M nodes).
Is there any why in `networkx` to implement it(I mean a written function)? 
I'm going to sample from the nodes uniformly. (I just need a tool in networkx)

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information about what you are trying to do.  What is it you want to learn from sampling?  Sample edges? Sample nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say G is the graph and you want `k = 100` samples.

```
import random
k = 100
sampled_nodes = random.sample(G.nodes, k)
sampled_edges = random.sample(G.edges, k)
```

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest an improvement to the answer from @xyzjayne

```
import random
k = 100
sampled_nodes = random.sample(G.nodes, k)
sampled_graph = G.subgraph(sampled_nodes)
```

This will preserve correct edge connectivity from the parent graph

Comment: do you know whether networkx allows a subgraph method like this where I pass it the edges I want to keep? I need to take a subgraph of a graph by taking 15% of the edges at random. That is, I just want the edges I sample to be preserved. Is it best then to just make a new graph object with these sampled edges?

Comment: @DavidIreland I don't know if you found it already. I found this method in the [networkx documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.classes.graphviews.subgraph_view.html#networkx.classes.graphviews.subgraph_view).